# INCLUDEPICTURE use an alternate jpg if MERGEFIELD "filename".jpg is not valid

Tags: mergefield, fieldcodes

I keep track of hikes we do in an EXCEL spreadsheet. I use WORD to create journal pages using a lot of MERGEFIELDS. I have clean maps of parks. After we do a hike, I use an editor to draw a route on the clean map of where we hiked producing a route map.

I would like to INCLUDEPICTURE the route map if there is one, otherwise a clean map. For these examples "Death Valley Map.jpg" does exist, "Death Valley Map Route.jpg" does not exist.

I cannot see that "{ IF TRUE ..." ever does anything. Is there some WORD option or switch that needs to be set? My problem is that I cannot get any if test to branch false when the file does not exist.

| Test Case | Test Result |
| --- | --- |
| `{ IF "Death Valley Map.jpg" }` | null |
| `{ IF "Death Valley Map Route.jpg" }` | null |
| `{ IF "Death Valley Map.jpg" "GoodA" "BadA" }` | GoodA |
| `{ IF "Death Valley Map Route.jpg" "GoodB" "BadB" }` | GoodB |
| `{ IF TRUE "Death Valley Map.jpg" }` | Death Valley Map.jpg |
| `{ IF TRUE "Death Valley Map Route.jpg" }` | Death Valley Map Route.jpg |
| `{ IF TRUE "Death Valley Map.jpg" "GoodC" "BadC" }` | Death Valley Map.jpg |
| `{ IF TRUE "Death Valley Map Route.jpg" "GoodD" "BadD" }` | Death Valley Map Route.jpg |
| `{ IF { IF TRUE "Death Valley Map.jpg" } "GoodE" "BadE" }` | GoodE |
| `{ IF { IF TRUE "Death Valley Map Route.jpg" } "GoodF" "BadF" }` | GoodF |
| `{ IF { IF TRUE "Death Valley Map.jpg" } <> "" "GoodG" "BadG" }` | GoodG |
| `{ IF { IF TRUE "Death Valley Map Route.jpg" } <> "" "GoodH" "BadH" }` | GoodH |
| `{ IF { INCLUDEPICTURE "{ IF TRUE "Death Valley Map.jpg" }" \d } "GoodI" "BadI" }` | GoodI |
| `{ IF { INCLUDEPICTURE "{ IF TRUE "Death Valley Map Route.jpg" }" \d } "GoodJ" "BadJ" }` | GoodJ |
| `{ IF { IF TRUE { INCLUDEPICTURE "{ IF TRUE "Death Valley Map.jpg" }" \d } } "GoodK" "BadK" }` | GoodK |
| `{ IF { IF TRUE { INCLUDEPICTURE "{ IF TRUE "Death Valley Map Route.jpg" }" \d } } "GoodL" "BadL" }` | GoodL |
| `{ IF { IF TRUE { INCLUDEPICTURE "{ IF TRUE "Death Valley Map.jpg" }" \d } } <> "" "GoodM" "BadM" }` | GoodM |
| `{ IF { IF TRUE { INCLUDEPICTURE "{ IF TRUE "Death Valley Map Route.jpg" }" \d } } <> "" "GoodN" "BadN" }` | GoodN |

Screen shots in case I didn't type exactly:

[screen shot of test cases](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHn1c.jpg)

[screen shot of test results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3KrH.png)